# Obtener datos de un objeto en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

ya se que no es la manera de preguntar, pero estoy empezando en Laravel y me han mandado un ejercicio en clase y no sé cómo seguir.
Me piden mostrar un alumno (indicando su id), he creado la tabla y el modelo con artisan, he rellenado dos objetos en la bases de datos de phpmyadmin, en el modelo he puesto esto:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App/Alumno;
class Alumno extends Model{
    public function mostrar($id){
        $alumno= Alumno::find($id);
        return View::make(alumno);
    }
}
```

Y en el fichero web.php lo siguiente:

```
Route::get('alumno/1','Alumno@mostrar');
```

No sé exactamente lo que hay que hacer, ni siquiera si lo anterior está bien.
He buscado por internet, pero me he liado más.
Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estas trabajando con Laravel tienes que pensar en MVC (aún que Laravel tiene más capas).

Lo que tendríamos que hacer:

1° Crear y definir el modelo y el controlador

```
php artisan make:model Tabla -c
```

Esto nos genera un modelo en  en `App/` y un controlador en `App/Http/Controllers`.

En el modelo es donde configuraremos los datos de la tabla algo como

Archivo `App\Tabla.php`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tabla extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Tabla'; // Nombre de la tabla
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // Clave primaria

    // Columnas de la tabla
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','apellidos'];

}
```

En el controlador es donde ejecutamos la lógica, algo como:

Archivo `App\Http\Controllers\TablaController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// Incluimos el modelo
use App\Tabla;

class TablaController extends Controller
{
// Creamos un método para atender la peticion llamado show
    public function show($id)
    {
        // Buscamos el id en la tabla
        $dato = Tabla::find($id);
        // retornamos la vista con los datos 
        return view('tabla.show')->with('dato', $dato);
        // with() nos permite pasar variables a la vista
        // el primer parámetros es el nombre con el que estará disponible en la vista
        // el segundo son los datos. 
    }
}
```

2° Crear y definir la ruta y la vista.

Para la vista vamos a la ruta `resources/views/` y creamos una nueva carpeta para guardar las vistas que usará nuestro controlador con el nombre `tabla` (para el ejemplo) y dentro de esta creamos un archivo con el nombre de la vista con extensión `.blade.php` (show.blade.php para el ejemplo).

Una vez hecho lo anterior abrimos el archivo creado `resources/views/tabla/show.blade.php` y podemos definir la vista, además tendremos disponible la variable `$dato` que retornamos junto a la vista en el controlador.

Por ejemplo

```
Id: {{ $dato->id }} <br>
Nombre: {{ $dato->nombre }} <br>
Apellidos: {{ $dato->apellidos }} <br>
```

Ya sólo nos falta definir la ruta, para ello vamos al archivo `routes/web.php` y creamos una ruta que apunte a nuestro controlador, por ejemplo

```
Route::get('/mi/ruta/{id}', 'TablaController@show');
// {id} Será la variable que recogeremos en el controlador
// en $id:  public function show($id)
```

Para acceder a este ejemplo deberíamos utilizar la url `dominio.es/mi/ruta/1`

Answer (score 1):

Algunos puntos para que funcione su ejemplo, en primer lugar debería crear un controlador para manejar esto, en consola ejecute

```
php artisan make:controller AlumnoController
```

En el archivo `AlumnoController` creado dentro de `App/Http/Controllers` cree un método `show` y agregue el código que tiene en mostrar y borre esa parte del modelo , con la modificación de usar `findOrFail` para que si dado un id y este no se encuentra registrado regrese un error `404`

```
public function show($id)
{
    $alumno= Alumno::findOrFail($id);
    return view('alumno',compact('alumno'));
}
```

Luego en su ruta `routes.php` apunte a ese método del controlador añadiendo el `id` como parámetro a la ruta

```
Route::get('alumno/{id}','AlumnoController@show')->name('alumno.show');
```

Ya restaría añadir como desea mostrar en su vista `alumno.blade.php` , por ejemplo

```
<h2>{{ $alumno->name }}</h2>
```

Ya ahora accediendo desde navegador a la ruta obtendrá el usuario dependiendo del parámetro de la `URL`.

**Edit**

Cómo paso a considerar , si su modelo es Alumno , Laravel interpreta que la tabla será `alumnos`, por lo tanto sí su tabla se llama diferente es necesario especificar el nombre mediante el atributo `$table` , adicionalmente si luego desea añadir masivamente registros  a base de datos mediante su modelo , debe especificar en el array `fillable` las columnas de su tabla.

```
class Tabla extends Model
{
    // nombre de la tabla
    protected $table = 'nombretabla'; 

    // Columnas de la tabla para insert masivo
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','apellido','edad'];

}
```

Comment: y el model se deja completamente vacio?

Comment: Como se llama tu tabla? Solo para mostrar datos puede ir vacío, el nombre de la tabla lo especifica con `protected $table = 'nombretabla' ;` en su modelo , igual actualicé mi respuesta con este detalle.

Comment: Ya se que debo marcar la respuesta correcta, pero he probado las dos y no me funciona ninguna.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla en qué paso se quedó? ¿Tiene errores? ¿Cuál es el escenario actual de código? , el código de la respuesta está probado y funciona , debería funcionarle también.