# Obtener datos de un usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Me piden mostrar los datos de un usuario(mediante su id), he creado la tabla y el modelo con artisan, he rellenado dos objetos en la bases de datos de **phpmyadmin**, en el modelo he puesto esto:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Firma extends Model
{
protected $table = 'empleados'; // Nombre de la tabla
protected $primaryKey = 'id_empleado'; // Clave primaria

// Columnas de la tabla
protected $fillable = ['id_perfil','nombre_empleado','puesto','telefono_empleado','email_empleado','direccion_empleado','status_empleado','date_added'];
}
```

En el controlador esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// Incluimos el modelo
use App\Firma;

class FirmaController extends Controller
{
// Creamos un método para atender la peticion llamado show
public function Index($id)
{
    // Buscamos el id en la tabla
    $dato = Auth::user()->id;
    // retornamos la vista con los datos 
    return view('firmas')->with('dato', $dato);
    // with() nos permite pasar variables a la vista
    // el primer parámetros es el nombre con el que estará disponible en la vista
    // el segundo son los datos. 
}
}
```

Defini la ruta:

```
Route::get('/firmas', 'FirmaController@index')->name('firmas');
```

Pero cuando quiero mostrar los datos que tiene la tabla en la base de datos asi:

```
{{ $dato->nombre }}
```

Me sale el error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\FirmaController::Index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"
```

No se en que me estoy equivocando, solo quiero mostrar datos que tengo en una tabla y segui este [tutorial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134238/obtener-datos-de-un-objeto-en-laravel)

Comment: esta linea esta mal: `$dato = Auth::user()->id;`, eh ahi solo recuperas el `id` del usuario logueado, osea `$dato` tiene un valor numerico como 1,2,3,4,5...,

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el controlador, no esta realizando  una consulta para eso dejé añadir el siguiente código

```
$dato = Auth::user()->id;
$dato=Firma::where('id_perfil',$dato)->get();
var_dump($dato);
```

solo me traer el id de campo, no me traer el id del registro

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// Incluimos el modelo
use App\Firma;

class FirmaController extends Controller
{
// Creamos un método para atender la peticion llamado show
public function Index($id)
{
    // Buscamos el id en la tabla
    $dato = Auth::user()->id;
    $dato=Firma::where('id',$dato)->get();
    var_dump($dato);//me imprimer la consulta 
    exit();//en caso que revisar los datos 
    // retornamos la vista con los datos 
    return view('firmas')->with('dato', $dato);
    // with() nos permite pasar variables a la vista
    // el primer parámetros es el nombre con el que estará disponible en la vista
    // el segundo son los datos. 
}
}
```

Comment: Esto no es del todo correcto, pues en su vista espera utilizar el `$dato` como un objeto y no como una colección. Entonces sería `first()` en lugar de `get()`. Por otro lado, cual sería la función de `exit()`?

Answer (score 0):

Hay un par de cosas erróneas en tu código.

### Obs 1: Declaración y llamada del método `index`

Fíjate como está declarado el método:

```php
public function Index($id) { /* ... */ } // ojo también con la mayúscula.
```

Este método espera recibir un argument (`$id`). Por otro lado, esta es la manera en cómo es llamado desde tus rutas:

```php
Route::get('/firmas', 'FirmaController@index')->name('firmas');
```

Al no haber ningún [parámetro de ruta](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters) no se está pasando ningún argumento hacia el método, esto es lo que causa el error recibido:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\FirmaController::Index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Este error te dice que el método espera un argumento pero recibió menos.

Para solucionarlo, bastaría como añadir el parámetro en la ruta anteriormente mencionada, así:

```php
Route::get('/firmas/{id}', 'FirmaController@index')->name('firmas');
```

De este modo, el valor de `id` es enviado como primer argumento en el método `index`.

### Obs 2: El método `index`

Noto que la variable `$id` realmente no es utilizada en tu función. Según los comentarios que mencionas en tu función, este método es uno de tipo `show`, los cuales suelen mostrar un elemento en particular. Ahora, hay dos opciones que tú podrías estar interesado:

(**Opción A**) Devolver la firma del usuario con id = `$id`

(**Opción B**) Devolver la firma del usuario con sesión activa (logueado)

#### Opción A

Para hacer esto realizar lo siguiente:

```php
public function index($id)
{
    // Buscamos el id en la tabla
    $usuario = App\Firma::find($id);
    // retornamos la vista con los datos 
    return view('firmas')->with('dato', $usuario);
}
```

#### Opción B

Para la opción B realizamos lo siguiente:

```php
public function index() // como no se usará el id, eliminamos el argumento
{
    // Buscamos el id en la tabla
    $usuario = App\Firma::find(auth()->id());
    // retornamos la vista con los datos
    return view('firmas')->with('dato', $usuario);
}
```

---

### Observación

En tu código realizaste lo siguiente:

```php
$dato = Auth::user()->id;
```

Esto te trae el `id` del usuario logueado, más no el objeto completo, por lo que el siguiente código en tu viste debe de arrojarte error dado que `$dato` no es un objeto sino un `integer`:

```php
{{ $dato->nombre }}
```

Si quiere devolver el objeto completo puedes hacer esto:

```php
$dato = App\Firma::find(Auth::user()->id);
```