# problema con una consulta eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

mi problema es el siguiente no logro capturar la id para realizar la función de actualizar me da el siguiente error: undefined index: id este es el codigo:

```
public function getUpdate() {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $blogPosts = BlogPost::find($id);
    $titleValue = $blogPosts['title'];
    $contentValue = $blogPosts['content'];

    return $this->render('admin/update-post.twig', [
        'titleValue' => $titleValue,
        'contentValue' => $contentValue,
        'id' => $id
    ]);     
}
```

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta puedes ver un ejemplo mas o menos completo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134238/obtener-datos-de-un-objeto-en-laravel/134249#134249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo la solucion para ese problema es, cuando estas mandando el id por medio del metodo get, tendrias que hacer algo asi.

> http://localhost/update/{id}

Lo cual luego en la funcion get lo vas a recibir como un argumento.

```
public function getUpdate($id) {
    $blogPosts = BlogPost::find($id);
    $titleValue = $blogPosts['title'];
    $contentValue = $blogPosts['content'];

    return $this->render('admin/update-post.twig', [
        'titleValue' => $titleValue,
        'contentValue' => $contentValue,
        'id' => $id
    ]);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo routes.php tienes que poner la variable id para que en tu controller se pueda recoger, por ejemplo

```
Route::get('/update/{id}', 'TuControlador@getUpdate');
```

Y en el controlador en tu función lo único que tienes que hacer es iniciar esa variable :

```
public function getUpdate($id) {
    $blogPosts = BlogPost::find($id);
    //resto de tu codigo
}
```

Comment: Esto es lo correcto, pero cuando se comienza a usar el framework de laravel, supongo que el aun no ha comenzado a usarlo